# Accessing Raw Gamer Profile Picture

Tags: xbox-live

I am using the new XBox Live API for C# (https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api-csharp) for official access through a UWP app.

I am able to authenticate fine and reference the XBox Live user in context.

```
SignInResult result = await user.SignInAsync(); 
XboxLiveUser user = new XboxLiveUser();
```

Success!  However, I can't seem to find an appropriate API call to return *XboxUserProfile* or *XboxSocialProfile*.  Both of these classes contain URLs to the player's raw gamer pics.  After reviewing MSDN documentation and the GH library it isn't clear to me how this is achieved.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below sample should work if you meet the following pre requisits:

1. Reference the Shared Project that contains the API from your project and don't reference the "Microsoft.Xbox.Services.UWP.CSharp" project
2. Copy all source code files from the "Microsoft.Xbox.Services.UWP.CSharp" project into your project
3. Include the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package into your project

Steps 1 & 2 are important as this allows you to access the "internal" constructors which otherwise would be protected from you.

Code to retrieve the profile data:

```
        XboxLiveUser user = new XboxLiveUser();
        await user.SignInSilentlyAsync();

        if (user.IsSignedIn)
        {
            XboxLiveContext context = new XboxLiveContext(user);
            PeopleHubService peoplehub = new PeopleHubService(context.Settings, context.AppConfig);
            XboxSocialUser socialuser = await peoplehub.GetProfileInfo(user, SocialManagerExtraDetailLevel.None);
            // Do whatever you want to do with the data in socialuser
        }
```

You may still run into an issue like I did. When building the project you may face the following error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'UserPicker' does not exist in the current
>   context   ...\System\UserImpl.cs  142 Active

If you get that error make sure you target Win 10.0 Build 14393.

Comment: Thanks, Zweistein!  For the Xbox live API devs who may be following stackoverflow... I would be very interested in understanding the rationale behind hiding this data.

Comment: I don't think they hiding the information. In another request for help I read that the only way to use the API at the moment is that you incorporate it into your project. They plan to release a NuGet package later on but no dates were mentioned.

Comment: Correct, we're not hiding the information.  It is accessible using the SocialManager classes, but it's just a little complicated right now.  It will be simplified.  You can see the UserProfile script from the Unity plugin (https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin/blob/master/Assets/Xbox%20Live/Scripts/UserProfile.cs#L77) for an example of how to use SocialManager to get the user profile info.  SocialManager handles caching and updating the data for you which is why it's preferred over using the PeopleHubService directly.

Comment: To be honest PeopleHub is a little bit more straight forward but I can see the advantages of SocialManager in the long run.